# single node_modules folder for multiple projects

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a list of websites like this:

```
project1/site
project2/site
project4/site
...
projectN/site
```

Each `site` folder has inside `node_modules` folder, `gruntfile.js` file and a `package.json` file. So they look like this:

```
project1/site/gruntfile.js
project1/site/package.json
project1/site/node_modules/
...
projectN/site/gruntfile.js
projectN/site/package.json
projectN/site/node_modules/
```

Everything is working fine with my tasks, plugins and stuff.

I am wondering if I can work this out with **just one** `node_modules` **folder** on my root folder as my websites are using similar tasks.

```
project1/site/
project2/site/
...
projectN/site/
/node_modules/
```

Is this even possible? What do I need to do?

Comment: `require` automatically goes up directories until it finds a `node_modules` dir containing the module you want, so that would work.  What's your plan for the `package.json` files?  Do you still want them separate, or would you combine them?

Comment: As @AaronDufour said, I would recommend either a parent "project" directory where you store everything. Unfortunately, there is no other way to share Node module dependencies across projects without using the global flag, which is [highly discouraged for project dependencies](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation).

Comment: There's no special plan for my `package.son` file. I am just using slightly different tasks on my `gruntfile.js` for each projects (Eg: One projects uses Sass, other uses Less and so on). This is because some projects are either old or other people have been working on them. But overall they share similar tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-g` flag with `npm` to install modules globally, as in:
`npm install -g <modulename>`
This will install all the modules so they are accessible to all your node projects.

And then you can create a link for each of the projects to the required modules using `npm link`, as explained in the link @jakerella [referred to](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation):

> ...there are some cases where you want to do both. Coffee-script and
> Express both are good examples of apps that have a command line
> interface, as well as a library. In those cases, you can do one of the
> following:
>
> 2. Install it globally, and then npm link coffee-script or npm link
>    express (if you’re on a platform that supports symbolic links.) Then
>    you only need to update the global copy to update all the symlinks as
>    well.

See the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Comment: That would not be advised as then you have no way to tie the installed modules to the project. The `package.json` file cannot be used in combination with the global flag (`-g`). From the [npm blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation): "Just like how global variables are kind of gross, but also necessary in some cases, global packages are important, but best avoided if not needed."

Comment: @jakerella, the same npm blog page refers to a potential solution for the OP - to use `npm link` - updated my answer accordingly. Considering the requirement of the OP, this may not be beautiful, but definitely a working solution, even if you do not agree with it...

Comment: Removed the -1 for the extra explanation, although I still don't agree with global installation as the solution. Thanks for taking the time to update your answer!