# How can I require node modules across disk partitions?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, partition, pnpm, mender

- **Node.js Version**: 14.15.0
- **OS**: Raspbian
- **Scope (install, code, runtime, meta, other?)**: require

I have a Node program that I run on Raspberry Pi 4. I've recently started using a OTA deployment system called Mender to push updates to my code on remote RPis. Mender creates a partition system that uses two 3.5GB partitions, one as the main and the other as a rollback in the event of a failed deployment. And it has a 3rd partition `/data`, that is around 20GB in my case, for things that need to be persisted between updates.

I was unable to get my entire application and all of it's node module dependencies into the 3.5GB partition. So I moved the `node_modules` directory to the `/data` partition and created a symlink that points back to my project directory(`home/pi/myProject`). This works for module installs but when I try to `require` an installed module from within my project an error is thrown;

```js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/pubsub'
Require stack:
- /home/pi/myProject/pwrMngmnt.js
- /home/pi/myProject/[eval]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myProject/pwrMngmnt.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/pi/myProject/pwrMngmnt.js',
    '/home/pi/myProject/[eval]'
  ]
}
```

Is there a configuration I need to set to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing a symlink, you could specify the `NODE_PATH` environment variable.
Quoting [the NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)
: *"NODE_PATH was originally created to support loading modules from varying paths before the current module resolution algorithm was defined."*

`NODE_PATH` is still supported and could perfectly fit your use-case IMO. Don't forget to fix file permissions if needed (using `chmod` and `chown`).

For instance:

```sh
export NODE_PATH="/data/node_modules"
node <your script>
```

Furthermore, you can ask *npm* or [*yarn*](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-modules-folder) to install modules in this directory.

With *yarn*:

```sh
yarn install --modules-folder /data/node_modules
```

With *npm*:

```sh
mkdir -p /data/node_modules
npm install --prefix /data
```

---

Possible related questions:

- [Specify path to node_modules in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json)
- [How to npm install to a specified directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469515/how-to-npm-install-to-a-specified-directory)

Comment: I tried this earlier but it didn't change the error. Do you know does `NODE_PATH` need to be set relative to my node application's directory in `home/pi/myProject`, where `home` and`data` are sibling directories? Or is setting an absolute path as you have shown correct?

Comment: I did a quick test with an absolute path and it works well. I tested with "npm install --prefix /tmp/node_test" and "NODE_PATH=/tmp/node_test/node_modules". Without the NODE_PATH I got a "MODULE_NOT_FOUND" error. With the NODE_PATH, I don't have any issue.

Comment: Cool. I was just reading [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37771/setting-system-wide-path-not-working-in-etc-environment) about how to set global environment variables on Raspbian. The answer accepted recommends adding a file to `profile.d` that sets the variable. Do you know if it matters from either a Raspbian OR Node perspective what you name the file?

Comment: Well, your question is not clear for me. It depends how you start your node script/daemon. Do you start it from your tty ? From a init script (e.g. systemd) ? From another tool ? I would recommend to read the following documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables Pay attention that it's an Ubuntu documentation. Some mechaisms could differ on Raspbian. I also saw this Debian wiki page: https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables ... but it looks pretty "old"/"outdated".

Comment: I need the program to run at boot/restart so I was planning on setting it up using `init.d` as described [here](https://www.instructables.com/Nodejs-App-As-a-RPI-Service-boot-at-Startup/)

Comment: This tuto looks outdated, I would recommend you to use systemd as [documented on RaspberryPi website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md) Please have a look in [Systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment)  (or [on stack](https://serverfault.com/a/413408/225643)) to know how to set an Environment variable for a systemd service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic structure

```
-|- data
 |- myProject
```

Create two folders node_modules, one in the source and one in the destination

```
mkdir myProject/node_modules
mkdir data/node_modules
sudo mount --bind data/node_modules/ myProject/node_modules/
```

You should have now something like this

```
-|- data -|- node_modules 
 |- myProject -|- node_modules
               |- index.js
               |- package.json
```

Now `myProject/node_modules` is a mirror of `data/node_modules`
This is extremely handy since you can even mount files from your network, if you want this to be permanant over restarts you can add an entry in `/etc/fstab`.