# doing npm install for each project takes too much space in drive

Tags: node.js, npm

is there any way to route npm install to a specific part of hard drive and when i do npm install it make node_module folder in that part of drive, and when i run any project it look for dependencies in that part of drive,
just like single **pool** for every project.

then if i have two projects with similar dependencies then i only need to `npm install` in one project so dependencies become available in **pool**, and no need to do `npm install` in another project just `npm start`

Thank you,
Inzamam Malik

Comment: you can try symlink the node_modules directory to somewhere else and then run npm install.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your point @MananVaghasiya

Comment: are you talking about https://www.npmjs.com/package/symlink?

Comment: no, I am talking about symbolic links, here are some other related questions as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183860/single-node-modules-folder-for-multiple-projects and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242763/having-project-name-node-modules-as-a-symlink

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve something close to what you are describing with the `link` option.

From https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#link:

> If true, then local installs will link if there is a suitable globally installed package.
>
> Note that this means that local installs can cause things to be installed into the global space at the same time. The link is only done if one of the two conditions are met:
>
> - The package is not already installed globally, or
> - the globally installed version is identical to the version that is being installed locally.

So you will still have some files in each project's `node_modules`, but you shouldn't have as large a folder.

To turn this behavior on, run:

```
npm config set link -g
```

**Edit:** There is no way you can avoid running `npm install` and having a `node_modules` folder. Node.js always looks in `node_modules` for dependencies (this behavior pre-dates `npm` itself). The `link` option will make `npm` create symlinks in `node_modules`, pointing to a common pool. That will reduce disc usage, but you cannot do away with `node_modules`.

Comment: are you sure that after doing this, `npm install` will not make `node_modules` folder in my project but install all dependencies in a pool?

Comment: `npm install` will always make a `node_modules` folder in your project. There is no way to get around that, due to the way Node.js works. The `link` option will just make the `node_modules` folder smaller in size (it will contain mostly symlinks).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PNPM](https://pnpm.js.org/) Package manager, It uses a global pool for dependencies.