# Do I need to install all the necessary npm packages(like for HTML,CSS or files) every time I build a new project with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, nodes

I am just so new to Webpack and NPM. So new that, I saw a webpack based project yesterday for the first time in my life. Well, it's difficult to grasp for a newbie like me. So, I installed the npm packages like `npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin` and few more to configure the webpack file. But I am little confused. So, all I want to know is, do I have do it(I mean go around and install the same npm packages) for each and every other projects that I build ? Because after installation the project file is like 50mb. Which is a lot I guess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [doing npm install for each project takes too much space in drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781991/doing-npm-install-for-each-project-takes-too-much-space-in-drive)

Comment: nope, that is not what I am asking for

Comment: It's recommended you install all these dependencies on per-project bases. However, if disk space is really your concern (which I doubt), you can globally install these plugins/loaders in the root `node_modules` folder. You can do this by `npm install -g html-webpack-plugin`. But you risk spending time debugging weird case when you hit version incompatibility.

Comment: why? Have you read the other question/answer? (edit the question to clarify.)

Comment: Its 2020, 50mb is not much. Besides you will `build` the project to deploy it on a hosting which wouldn't take that much space if you don't have large assets

Comment: node.js toolchains evolve so quick, things break a lot. I did show you a solution, but I really don't recommend it.

Comment: @hackape okay man thank you, that's all I wanted hear. I mean that 'you install all these dependencies on per-project bases'. And no disk space isn't my concern but I have this question now, the 40mb file, the whole file get loaded on the browser or just my files ?

Comment: Just your file. Those are building tools, not bundled result.

Comment: Side note. You might want to check out `parcel-bundler`. It's less configurable compared to `webpack`, but really hassle-free. It's my personal go-to choice as starting point of new projects these days.

Comment: @user202729 please read my question thoroughly.  It's not so confusing

Comment: @hackape thank you for your suggestion, I will take a look at it. Thanks again